# PyPDF doesn't seem to load signature object

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I'm trying to load a PDF document with a special signature (handwritten signature) object in it. Below is the code I'm using, where `blankdoc` is the PDF containing the signature.

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

page = PdfFileReader(file(blankdoc,"rb")).getPage(0)

output = PdfFileWriter()
output.addPage(page)

outputStream = file("destination.pdf", "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

So just loading the input PDF, and immediately writing to an output PDF - the problem is that the signature is lost somehow in the conversion.

Upon opening the input PDF in a text editor, I found the data corresponding to the signature, and it looks like some kind of custom signature object that gets decoded when it gets opened by the PDF viewer.

The data has indicators like the location/timestamp, and words like, "/eSign" and "IntegriSign" with about 50 lines of seemingly meaningless letters and numbers.

My goal is to be able to have pyPdf recognize this signature object - is there a way to read/write all the data in the PDF, including the signature?

Comment: The *meaningless letters and numbers* are probably the actual signature. Any "image" of the signature is worthless. It's the digital signature that counts. See my [presentation on digital signatures](http://www.slideshare.net/iTextPDF/digital-signatures-how-its-done-in-pdf-46029889) and our [webinar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3eebjsqbj44) for more info. Or maybe that *meaningless letters and numbers* sequence is a compressed stream of PDF syntax: the vector data that corresponds with somebody's signature.

Comment: Look at the document with [iText RUPS](http://itextpdf.com/product/itext_rups) and tell us if there's a signature form field, an annotation,... Whatever that looks like the object you're looking for.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thanks for the links. Let me clarify: I realize the letters and numbers are not meaningless. If I'm understanding your links correctly, if I wanted to modify the PDF before saving it it (ultimately, that is my goal), the hash would change, and the signature would no longer be valid

Comment: If your document has a *real* digital signature, then changing the document will invalidate the signature, otherwise it would be very easy to change signed contracts. If your document has a *fake* digital signature, such as some image that looks like a wet ink signature, but that isn't a *real* digital signature, then you can modify the document. (Obviously, the signature on such a document has no legal value.)